# What is the use of coefficient in in Regression

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, machine-learning

What is the meaning of coefficient values in Machine Learning. After I print

```
model.print_summary()
```

It shows, coefficient values of for each column. But I really don't know what is the meaning of `coef` in this?

```
                      coef  exp(coef)  se(coef)        z      p  lower 0.95  upper 0.95     
EXPERIENCE IN DAYS -0.0013     0.9987    0.0001 -22.8579 0.0000     -0.0015     -0.0012  ***
GENDER              0.4598     1.5838    0.0786   5.8536 0.0000      0.3059      0.6138  ***
GRADE              -0.7267     0.4835    0.0444 -16.3717 0.0000     -0.8136     -0.6397  ***
STAFFING_TYPE      -0.4950     0.6096    0.0413 -11.9870 0.0000     -0.5759     -0.4140  ***
```

Is Large coef value represents strong feature or weaker feature ?

What is the use What is the use of coefficient in in Regression?

Note: Here model represents linear regression.

Comment: It really depends on what "model" is. If this is a linear regression model, then [roughly] the coefficient of a feature represents how much the response variable changes if you increase that feature by one unit and hold all other features constant.

Comment: @angryavian - Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention that, It's a linear regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a linear regression model with $n$ exogenic variables, the model is

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \ldots + \beta_n x_n + \xi
$$

So you are looking for coefficients $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\ldots$, $\beta_n$, so that the difference between the output ($y$) of your model for a given input vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ compared to your data is minimized.

In other words the coefficients determine how much a change of each input variable contributes to the output variable. For example, a coefficient of 0.4598 for your variable $x_2$ (Gender) means that the output variable $y$ increases for 0.4598 if the variable Gender increases for 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can I consider GENDER is a strong feature among them?

Comment: Strong is not the correct word here. Read the coefficients like this: if GENDER increases for 1, the output variable increases for 0.4598. If EXPERIENCE IN DAYS increases for 1, the output variable decreases for -0.0013 (given that all other input variables stay the same), etc.

Comment: So Coeff represents influence of outcome of `y` right?